# Is a groovy String also implicitly a Collection?

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy

Weak typing in groovy is great and all, but this one has me scratching my head:

```
myList = new java.util.ArrayList(['foo', 'foo', 'foobar', 'barfoo'])
myList.removeAll('foo')
println myList // prints [foobar, barfoo]
```

`removeAll` needs a `Collection` as a parameter. [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29). Why does line #2 work when I’m sending in a `String` - Is a groovy String also implicitly a Collection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather Groovy provides enhancements to JDK `Collection` interface one of which is [`Collection::removeAll(Object[] data)`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) and this allows such behaviour: one element `foo` seems to be implicitly converted into one-item array as with `varargs`.

Answer (score 2):

No. Groovy adds [an extension method `Collection.removeAll(Object[])`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) that can accept varargs. Your `'foo'` gets turned into a single-element array.

In the future, place a breakpoint on methods like this and Step Into; you'll see exactly what value was passed in and whether you are stepping into an extension method or something else unexpected.